# Displaying ArrayList of Google Datastore entities using Zk MVVM => bad output

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, zk

I'm using:

- Google App Engine with Google Datastore
- Zk 8.5 with the MVVM design

I'm having an issue trying to display an arrayList in a grid like this:

```
<grid model="@load(vm.clientListModel)" >
    <template name="model">
        <row >

            <label value="@load(each.nom)"/>

        </row>
    </template>
 </grid>
```

It will display for each row something in this format :
**com.mypackage.entity.Client@3c3f784e**

My Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6603526588403725762L;
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Index
    private String nom;
    private Sexe sexe;
    private Contact contact;

    @Load
    private Ref<Mesures> mesures;

    public Client() {
        contact = new Contact();

    }
}
```

My Service:

```
public  List<Client> getAll() {
        return ofy().consistency(Consistency.STRONG).load().type(Client.class).order("nom").list();
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class RepertoireViewModel extends PageViewModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3656947251943967000L;

    private ListModelList<Client> clientListModel;

    private List<Client> clients;

    @Init
    public void init() {
        clients = ClientService.getInstance().getAll();
        clientListModel = new ListModelList<>(clients);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add more information about what you want to happen and what actually happens? I think it has to do with String serialization, but I am not sure which part has the problem.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer. It should display a list of Name. Instead it's displaying something in this format : com.mypackage.entity.Client@3c3f784e

Comment: Again, please provide a minimal, full example. For example, your Client class. I suspect it needs a `toString` method, but it is hard to say without this code.

Comment: I edited the post: I included the classes

Comment: @CheikhHassanCisse for us to be able to help, you need to reduce your example code. Remove all unnecessary properties of Client, provide mock data instead of showing use the service, etc. Doing this, maybe you'll find the problem already. I tried your zul after removing all code that does not compile and it worked fine, showing the name. Could it be that you should bind against `vm.clientResultModel` instead of `vm.clientResultList`? Did you debug whether `nom` is correctly set in the `Client` objects? It looks like the grid renders ignores your template and just uses (`Client.toString()`).

Comment: Also, what does the "..." inside the grid mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot Malte for your answer and suggestion. I will reduce my example code as sugested. I used to display an ArrayList of object without problem in my previous application but it was not with Google App Engine (I used WildFly). If I printing the list in my ViewModel (a POJO) it's displayed nice, I'm only having the problem in the zul using a grid or a listbox with model="@load(vm.myItems)"

Comment: the ... was just to reduce unecessary code like columns definitions

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is related to the rowRenderer.

In an normal environnement like WildFly(not a Clustering environnement like Google App Engine) I don't have this problem with model="@load(vm.clientListModel)"

If I add this code to the RepertoireViewModel.java

```
public RowRenderer<Client> getRenderer(){
        return new RowRenderer<Client>() {

            @Override
            public void render(Row row, Client data, int index) throws Exception {
                final Label lblNom = new Label(data.getNom());
                final Label lblTelephone = new Label(data.getContact().getTelephone());

                final Div div = new Div();
                Button btn1 = new Button();
                btn1.setIconSclass("z-icon-eye");
                Button btn2 = new Button();
                btn2.setIconSclass("z-icon-edit");
                Button btn3 = new Button();
                btn3.setIconSclass("z-icon-remove");

                div.appendChild(btn1);
                div.appendChild(btn2);
                div.appendChild(btn3);

                row.appendChild( lblNom );
                row.appendChild( lblTelephone );
                row.appendChild( div);
            }
        };
    }
```

and change my view to this:

```
    <grid rowRenderer="@load(vm.renderer)"  model="@load(vm.clientListModel)" hflex="min"  style="margin-top: 20px;" xmlns="zul" xmlns:n="native"  emptyMessage="Liste vide">
                        <columns>
                            <column>
                                <textbox value="@save(vm.rechercheNom)" instant="true" onChange="@command('filter')" hflex="1" placeholder="Nom" />
                            </column>
                            <column>
                                <textbox value="@save(vm.rechercheTelephone)" instant="true" onChange="@command('filter')" hflex="1" placeholder="Téléphone" />
                            </column>
                            <column align="center" label=""/>
                        </columns>

   </grid>
```

It works fine.

If someone knows how to make it work in the MVVM way it would be welcomed else I can use this solution

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the problem was from the use of xmlns="native" xmlns:u="zul" xmlns:x="xhtml" in my zul. After I have removed it, it works fine.

Best regards